# comparing two dates in javascript with years < 100 and > 100

Tags: javascript

why javascript Date comparison is returning wrong answer?

```
new Date(99,0,1)< new Date(101,0,1) //result =false and year 99 is shown as 1999
```

i also found that  date.getTime() method also works similarly and returned wrong answer.

Comment: What do you expect `101` to get you ? I'd assume that was the year 101, i,e, not 2101, worst case I'd expect it to be invalid, and still not 2101?

Comment: [2-digit years map to 1900-1999](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Two_digit_years_map_to_1900_-_1999). You can set the year explicitly with `.setFullYear()`.

Comment: actually i was using it in a form and wanted that it would  correctly validate in cases of any years but validation failed when someone tried  year 99 < year 1977

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(new Date(99,0,1));
console.log(new Date(101,0,1));
```

The constructor for `Date` object is  is like

`new Date(year, month[, date[, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);`

**If the `year` value is from 0 to 99 then Javascript maps that value to the year from 1900 to 1999.**

Therefore the `new Date(99,0,1)` is mapped to `1999-01-01` and the date `new Date(101,0,1)` is mapped to `0101-01-01` which is smaller and hence you are getting the result.